# df.to_sql (TypeError: The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.)

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I was trying to save a DataFrame to mysql table, the following code occured the error:TypeError: The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.

```
engine2=sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pyodbc://user:pwd@localhost/sakila?DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver}?charset=utf8')
df.to_sql('test12',engine2,index=False)
```

I cannot find a resolution, what can I do?

update:
df:

```
cnxn2=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=sakila;UID=user;PWD=pwd')
df=pd.read_sql("select * from actor",cnxn2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlPdN.jpg)

error：

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-0c720eb43923> in <module>()
      1 engine2=sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pyodbc://root:Johnny2010@localhost/sakila?DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver}?charset=utf8')
----> 2 df.to_sql('test',engine2,index=False)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in to_sql(self, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
   2125         sql.to_sql(self, name, con, schema=schema, if_exists=if_exists,
   2126                    index=index, index_label=index_label, chunksize=chunksize,
-> 2127                    dtype=dtype)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in to_sql(frame, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
    448     pandas_sql.to_sql(frame, name, if_exists=if_exists, index=index,
    449                       index_label=index_label, schema=schema,
--> 450                       chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)


...
...

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1191                         statement,
   1192                         parameters,
-> 1193                         context)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    506     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 507         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

TypeError: The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.
```

Comment: What is ```test12´´´? Try to give a sample of your ´´´df´´´ for reproducibility.

Comment: test12 is the name the table in mysql, it is not created before, is it that the table should created first before the dataframe is inserted?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't given any info on the dataframe you wish to upload to your db, I give you an example that works. Compare it to what you have:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,3))
df2 = df.where(df < .2, None)
DF = df2.fillna(value=np.nan)
DF = DF.rename(columns = {0:'a', 1:'b',2:'c'})
csv_database = create_engine('sqlite:///csv_database.db', echo=False)
DF.to_sql("FACTS2", if_exists = 'replace',con=csv_database)
```

So, your `test12` is my `FACTS2`.
In the above, the dataframe looks like this

[image]

Comment: I was using mysql+pyodbc instead of sqlite, and do you create a new table or it already existed ?

Comment: If it doesn't already exist, it is created. In my example, it replaces any table named FACTs2. If you wish to append then ```if_exists = 'append'```.  For ```mysql+pyodbc``` it works the same.